# Ionic header hide content despite class "has-header"

Tags: html, css, ionic-framework

On an app with Ionic and AngularJs, I try to create a new template with a header. Unfortunately some content is hidden by the header.

Here is my code:

```html
<link href="http://code.ionicframework.com/1.0.0/css/ionic.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="bar bar-header bar-stable">
  <h1 class="title">XXX</h1>
</div>
<ion-content class="has-header">
  <div class="padding-horizontal">
    <h4 class="center">Sign in</h4>
    <button class="button button-block button-positive">Sign In</button>
  </div>
  <hr>
  <div class="padding-horizontal">
    <h4 class="center">Don't have an account?</h4>
    <button class="button button-block button-positive">Sign Up</button>
  </div>
</ion-content>
```

Or JsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/cyef9sxs/1/

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well you need to specify the position absolute and width for the ionic element.

```
.has-header {
  top: 44px;
  position:absolute;
  width: 100%;
}
```